# How to print first two words of a sentence in php

Tags: php, preg-split

I wanna print the first two words of a sentence,

```php
$txt = "Laravel PHP Node JS";
```

and expecting the output `Laravel PHP`

used below snippet is there any other way to simplify it?

```php
echo (implode(array_slice(preg_split("/\s+/", $txt), 0, 2),' '));
```

Comment: You're using the deprecated `implode` function signature... it will throw an error on PHP 8.

Comment: @HonkderHase Is there any other way to do this? And I am using 7 in my project.

Comment: There are probably different ways to do this. I would write it in more lines, with checks... actually write robust and well readable code, but that is only my personal preference. But what are you actually after?

Answer (score 2):

If with simpler you mean a single function call, you might for example match the first 2 "words" by matching 2 times one or more non whitespace characters with `\S+` with [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and check if there is a match.

```
$txt = "Laravel PHP Node JS";
if (preg_match("/\S+\h+\S+/", $txt, $match)) {
    echo $match[0];
}
```

Output

```
Laravel PHP
```